# How do I call a public method with options using a jQuery plugin boilerplate?

Tags: jquery

I've learned quite a bit about developing with jQuery, but one of the topics I am having trouble grasping is writing plugins. I use [this](http://stefangabos.ro/jquery/jquery-plugin-boilerplate-revisited/) plugin boilerplate to write my plugin. I want to have several public methods.

This is my JS:

```
(function($) {
    $.pluginA = function(element, options) {
        var defaults = {
            action: function(){}
        }
        var plugin = this;
        plugin.settings = {}
        var $element = $(element),
             element = element;
        plugin.init = function() {
            plugin.settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
            console.log('plugin A called')
        }
        plugin.method1 = function(){
          $element.on('click', function(e){
            plugin.settings.action;
            e.preventDefault();
          })
         }
        plugin.init();
    }
    $.fn.pluginA = function(options) {
        return this.each(function() {
            if (undefined == $(this).data('pluginA')) {
                var plugin = new $.pluginA(this, options);
                $(this).data('pluginA', plugin);
            }
        });
    }
    $.pluginB = function(element, options) {
        var defaults = {
            action: function(){}
        }
        var plugin = this;
        plugin.settings = {}
        var $element = $(element),
             element = element;
        plugin.init = function() {
            plugin.settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
            console.log('plugin B called')
        }
        plugin.method1 = function(){
          $element.on('click', function(e){
            alert("Plugin B action performed.");
            e.preventDefault();
          })
         }
        plugin.init();
    }
    $.fn.pluginB = function(options) {
        return this.each(function() {
            if (undefined == $(this).data('pluginB')) {
                var plugin = new $.pluginB(this, options);
                $(this).data('pluginB', plugin);
            }
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

This is the HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="action">Action</a>
<script>
(function($){
    $('#action').data('pluginA').method1({
        action: $().data('pluginB').method1()
  });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

The error that I keep getting is `Cannot read property '{nameofpublicmethod}' of undefined.` What exactly is not defined here? Is it data('pluginA') or something else? Some help would be greatly appreciated!